# how to deselect all vector lines in order to edit singular paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I imported a raster image into Illustrator. Using Image Trace in 3 Color I created vector lines to laser cut the image on plexi glass. I need to edit the individual lines and I can only select ALL of the vector lines from the image. How can I simply deselect the entire image to allow each path to be selected individually?

Comment: have you tried ungroping?

Comment: Maybe or maybe not a stupid question but have you expanded the trace?

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: Possibly `Object > Ungroup`
- Option 2: Possibly `Object > Compound Path > Release` -- This may, however, cause "holes' or "counters" to become filled shapes.
- Option 3: Possibly `Pathfinder Panel > Merge Button` *then* `Object > Ungroup`
- Option 4: Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to select individual anchors and paths in a group
- Option 5: You can also unselect all via <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -- but it really sounds like you need option 1 or 4.

You also need to click the <kbd>Expand</kbd> button on the **Control bar** across the top of the screen after tracing an image.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds crazy, but here is how I do what you need. Select a single path with the Open Arrow (not the Closed Arrow) icon. This tool may be enough for you to simply select a small part of the whole. But you may want to select more of the path. In that case, while "the small part" is selected (whether a point or a line), copy and paste. Without deselecting the pasted part, click an Undo. The Undo will return to your original path except this time the ENTIRE path is fully selected.